# How to sudo from exec function using nginx, php-fpm, and Arch Linux

Tags: nginx, php, archlinux

I can log in as any user and `sudo whoami` without password and get "root". When i try this with `php -r 'echo exec("sudo whoami");'` it works regardless of what user i am. But when i run this through the webserver (nginx) i get nothing. What gives?

`ps xau | grep php`

`root       207  0.0  2.6  19876  4992 ?        Ss   23:16   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/php-fpm.conf)
http       228  0.0  1.6  19876  3152 ?        S    23:16   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
http       229  0.0  1.6  19876  3144 ?        S    23:16   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root       326  0.0  0.3   2504   692 pts/0    S+   23:59   0:00 grep php`

Comment: sudo settings can be found in /etc/sudoers. With or without password - it's sudo settings.

Comment: yeah those work though. i've been there done that. The settings there behave as expected everywhere except through the webserver.

Comment: Probably you need to add here uid of php (`ps xau | grep php` for example) and sudoers file with all includes.

Comment: Now you need to check that `http` user can use `sudo` without password.

Comment: It can. i had to give it a bin/bash shell in order to log in. but once i did, it runs sudo fine without a password. i've rebooted with the new shell, still nothing.

Comment: `ALL ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/whoami` Just checked, all working fine for php-fpm.

Comment: Did you try it through a webserver using php?

Comment: Yes, php-fpm server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appended `2>&1` to my command to see errors and it said "sudo: command not found".

I then added `putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':/usr/sbin');` to my php script and it worked.

Comment: You should accept this answer as it is "the one that worked for you" :)